# Which is better: returning tuple or passing arguments to function as references?

Tags: c++, function

I created code where I have two functions `returnValues` and `returnValuesVoid`. One returns tuple of 2 values and other accept argument's references to the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> returnValues(const int a, const int b) {
    return std::tuple(a,b);
}

void returnValuesVoid(int &a,int &b) {
    a += 100;
    b += 100;
}

int main() {
    auto [x,y] = returnValues(10,20);

    std::cout << x ;
    std::cout << y ;

    int a = 10, b = 20;
    returnValuesVoid(a, b);

    std::cout << a ;
    std::cout << b ;
}
```

I read about http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding
which can destruct tuple to `auto [x,y]` variables.

Is `auto [x,y] = returnValues(10,20);` better than passing by references? As I know it's slower because it does have to return **tuple object** and **reference** just works on orginal variables passed to function so there's no reason to use it except cleaner code.

As `auto [x,y]` is **since C++17** do people use it on production? I see that it looks cleaner than `returnValuesVoid` which is void type and but does it have other advantages over passing by reference?

Comment: according to the CppCoreGuidelines the tuple is the preferred way: [F.21](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out-multi)

Comment: I prefer returning a hand-crafted `struct` the majority of the time. Over time that `struct` gets methods of its own; and everything scales up better. Java is particularly dogmatic about this. NRVO obviates value copies.

Comment: As you noticed, yes, returning tuples make code cleaner. Returning tuples is slower is not a case. C++ compiler optimizes it and uses move semantic for returned vars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at disassemble (compiled with GCC -O3):

It takes more instruction to implement tuple call.

```
0000000000000000 <returnValues(int, int)>:
   0:   83 c2 64                add    $0x64,%edx
   3:   83 c6 64                add    $0x64,%esi
   6:   48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
   9:   89 17                   mov    %edx,(%rdi)
   b:   89 77 04                mov    %esi,0x4(%rdi)
   e:   c3                      retq   
   f:   90                      nop

0000000000000010 <returnValuesVoid(int&, int&)>:
  10:   83 07 64                addl   $0x64,(%rdi)
  13:   83 06 64                addl   $0x64,(%rsi)
  16:   c3                      retq
```

But less instructions for the tuple caller:

```
0000000000000000 <callTuple()>:
   0:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
   4:   ba 14 00 00 00          mov    $0x14,%edx
   9:   be 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%esi
   e:   48 8d 7c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
  13:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  18 <callTuple()+0x18> // call returnValues
  18:   8b 74 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%esi
  1c:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  23:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  28 <callTuple()+0x28> // std::cout::operator<<
  28:   8b 74 24 08             mov    0x8(%rsp),%esi
  2c:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  33:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  38 <callTuple()+0x38> // std::cout::operator<<
  38:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  3c:   c3                      retq   
  3d:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)

0000000000000040 <callRef()>:
  40:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  44:   48 8d 74 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rsi
  49:   48 8d 7c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
  4e:   c7 44 24 08 0a 00 00    movl   $0xa,0x8(%rsp)
  55:   00 
  56:   c7 44 24 0c 14 00 00    movl   $0x14,0xc(%rsp)
  5d:   00 
  5e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  63 <callRef()+0x23> // call returnValuesVoid
  63:   8b 74 24 08             mov    0x8(%rsp),%esi
  67:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  6e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  73 <callRef()+0x33> // std::cout::operator<<
  73:   8b 74 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%esi
  77:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  7e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  83 <callRef()+0x43> // std::cout::operator<<
  83:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  87:   c3                      retq
```

I don't think there is any considerable performance different, but the tuple one is more clear, more readable.

Also tried inlined call, there is absolutely no different at all. Both of them generate exactly the same assemble code.

```
0000000000000000 <callTuple()>:
   0:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
   7:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   b:   be 6e 00 00 00          mov    $0x6e,%esi
  10:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  15 <callTuple()+0x15>
  15:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  1c:   be 78 00 00 00          mov    $0x78,%esi
  21:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  25:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   2a <callTuple()+0x2a> // TCO, optimized way to call a function and also return
  2a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000030 <callRef()>:
  30:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  37:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  3b:   be 6e 00 00 00          mov    $0x6e,%esi
  40:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  45 <callRef()+0x15>
  45:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi
  4c:   be 78 00 00 00          mov    $0x78,%esi
  51:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  55:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5a <callRef()+0x2a> // TCO, optimized way to call a function and also return
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer as you were first and provided detiled information about functions assembly code. Also I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkDEzfpdcSg&t=0s and as others wrote core guidelines propeses tuple aproach as a best practice.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on what's more readable and which approach provides a better intuition to the reader, and please keep the performance issues you might think that arise in the background.

A function that returns a tuple (or a pair, a struct, etc.) is yelling to the author that the function returns something, that almost always has some meaning that the user can take into account.

A function that gives back the results in variables passed by reference, may slip the eye's attention of a tired reader.

So, in general, prefer to return the results by a tuple.

---

Mike van Dyke pointed to this [link](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out-multi):

> F.21: To return multiple "out" values, *prefer returning a tuple or struct*
>
> Reason
>
> A return value is self-documenting as an "output-only"
>   value. Note that C++ does have multiple return values, by convention
>   of using a tuple (including pair), possibly with the extra convenience
>   of tie at the call site.
>
> [...]
>
> Exception
>
> Sometimes, we need to pass an object to a function to manipulate its state. In such cases, passing the object by reference `T&` is usually the right technique.

Comment: Another point: The body of the function can *read from* a reference argument, it *can't* read from a return value, so returning a tuple makes it *abundantly clear* that the caller doesn't need to initialise anything

Answer (score 2):

Using another compiler (VS 2017) the resulting code shows no difference, as the function calls are just optimized away.

```
int main() {
00007FF6A9C51E50  sub         rsp,28h  
    auto [x,y] = returnValues(10,20);

    std::cout << x ;
00007FF6A9C51E54  mov         edx,0Ah  
00007FF6A9C51E59  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF6A9C51F60h)  
    std::cout << y ;
00007FF6A9C51E5E  mov         edx,14h  
00007FF6A9C51E63  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF6A9C51F60h)  

    int a = 10, b = 20;
    returnValuesVoid(a, b);

    std::cout << a ;
00007FF6A9C51E68  mov         edx,6Eh  
00007FF6A9C51E6D  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF6A9C51F60h)  
    std::cout << b ;
00007FF6A9C51E72  mov         edx,78h  
00007FF6A9C51E77  call        std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF6A9C51F60h)  
}
00007FF6A9C51E7C  xor         eax,eax  
00007FF6A9C51E7E  add         rsp,28h  
00007FF6A9C51E82  ret
```

So using clearer code seems to be the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1):

What Zang said is true but not up-to the point. I ran the code provided in question with `chrono` to measure time. I think the answer needs to be edited after observing what happened.

For 1M iterations, time taken by function call via reference was 3ms while time taken by function call via `std::tie` combined with `std::tuple` was about 94ms.

Though the difference seems very less in practice, still tuple one will perform slightly slower. Hence, for performance intensive systems, I suggest using call by reference.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>

std::tuple<int, int> returnValues(const int a, const int b)
{
    return std::tuple<int, int>(a, b);
}

void returnValuesVoid(int &a, int &b)
{
    a += 100;
    b += 100;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        std::tie(x, y) = returnValues(a, b);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count()) << '\n';

    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        returnValuesVoid(a, b);
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count()) << '\n';
}
```